# Possibilidades input mask com lib jquery

Tags: jquery, lib, input-mask

Estou utilizando o `input-maks` para colocar uma mascara no campo porém estou tendo a dificuldade de setar um valor, por exemplo na minha mascara eu coloco

```
'data-mask'=>"00000,00"
 referente ao campo decimal(5,2);
```

Porém se quero colocar centavos tipo `50`, preciso de fazer 00000,50. Outro exemplo caso eu queira colocar 25,99 preciso colocar 00025,99. Caso eu force colocar a virgula antes o campo por padrão apaga e não me deixar escrever.

Estou utilizando `blade` para criação do campo texto

```
{{ Form::text( 'VAL_ESTOQ_PRODU', null,['class' => 'form-control input-mask', 'data-mask'=>"00000,00", 'placeholder'=>"00000,00", 'maxlength'=>"8", 'autocomplete'=>"off" ]) }}
```

Como posso resolver isto ?

O puglin que estou usando foi feito por:

```
 /**
 * jquery.mask.js
 * @version: v1.5.3
 * @author: Igor Escobar
 *
 * Created by Igor Escobar on 2012-03-10. Please report any bug at http://blog.igorescobar.com
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Igor Escobar http://blog.igorescobar.com
 *
 **/
```

Comment: não tenho ideia q package vc está usando, mas não seria só `,00` a mask?

Comment: colocando isto so usario ,99; ai no caso de fazer 115,00 nao daria

Comment: @gmsantos realmente nao sei informar qual estou usando, porém se entender o que quero e quiser indicar algum

Comment: A sua dúvida não está muito clara, entretanto não está relacionada com o Blade. Recomendo editar sua pergunta, juntamente com as tags e pesquisar sobre a lib em jquery q vc está usando

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que basta você definir a máscara como reversa, passando o objeto `{reverse: true}` no segundo parâmetro.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#price').mask('00000,00', {reverse: true});
  $('#price').keyup(function () {
    $('#flash').html($('#price').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.9/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input name="price" id="price" type="text" />
<div>Preço: R$ <span id="flash">0,00</span></div>
```

> Pressione **Executar** e veja o código em funcionamento.

Utilizando a notação HTML, para definir a máscara como reversa, basta adicionar o atributo `data-mask-reverse="true"`. Logo, com Blade, acredito que ficaria algo como:

```
{{ Form::text( 'VAL_ESTOQ_PRODU', null,['class' => 'form-control input-mask', 'data-mask'=>"00000,00", 'data-mask-reverse'=>"true", 'placeholder'=>"00000,00", 'maxlength'=>"8", 'autocomplete'=>"off" ]) }}
```

Comment: E para colocar o R$ na frente ?

Comment: E como vou passar revrse no data-tag ?

Comment: Editado. O que você quer dizer com "colocar R$ na frente"? Exibir apenas na máscara ou devem estar presentes no valor atual do input?

Comment: exibir apenas na mascara

Comment: Deu certinho aqui so esta faltando para ficar redondo o R$ na mascara na frente do valor

Comment: Acredito que só definindo a máscara como função JavaScript. Não tem como apenas utilizando a notação HTML. Não pode inserir esses caracteres direto no HTML antes do `input`?

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, porem acho que ele ira descer

Comment: Se esta API do Blade retorna o código HTML do input, basta fazer `R$ {{ Form::text(...) }}`. O `input`, por padrão é disposto em linha, logo estará perfeitamente alinhado com o texto, salvo se você o estilizou com CSS e alterou o comportamento padrão.